# Firebase Automatically Collected User Property Gender Data - How to Extract the Gender Data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

How to query Firebase Automated User Property Gender from Big Query. I used below query, the query is right, but after executing the query, **I am getting the result "The query returned no results"**

```
select app_info.id,app_info.version,
event_date,event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as category,
  param2.value.string_value as action,
  param3.value.string_value as label,
  param4.value.string_value as Gender,
  count(1) as totalevent,count( distinct user_pseudo_id ) as uniqueusers
From `Tablet_*`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2,
UNNEST(event_params) as param3,
UNNEST(user_properties) as param4
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20200203'  AND '20200203' 
and param1.key='category'
and param2.key='action' 
and param3.key='label' 
and param4.key='Gender'
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8
order by totalevent desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your query with the public table `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_*`, please validate the following:

1 The table suffix values to confirm the available range of dates:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT(_TABLE_SUFFIX) AS RANGE_DATES
  FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_*`
```

2 If the previous contains data in date '20200203', check your filters:

- param2.key='action'
- param3.key='label'
- param4.key='Gender'

For example, I tried to filter by 'action':

```
  SELECT event_date, param1.key
  FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) as param1
  where param1.key ='action'
```

**The query returned no results**

Comment: Thanks Issac for the response. Even after made above changes that you highlighted i am getting the same result "The query returned no results". Pls. Help

Comment: If there is data on 'Tablet_20200203' but no results are returned after adding the WHERE clause, it means that the query is fine, just that no row meets the criteria (e.g param1.key = 'action' doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks Issac for the response. i edited the above query. The above query without gender i am getting data / results (It is working fine). The above query with gender i am getting "The query returned no results". What went wrong, pls. help. Thanks

Comment: Nothing went wrong, you are just searching for non existent data. I would suggest to explore your data using [data studio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio) or [google sheets](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/analyze-your-business-data-explore-google-sheets-use-bigquery-too).